# Python pywinauto getting TimeoutError frequently

Tags: python, testing, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

Hi I am using Python pywinauto, and I am trying to validate UI elements in AUT , but out of 5 execution 3 times it fails saying "pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out" it halts the execution , and its not at the same place all the time it changes its occurrence in different line of code.

Here is the example error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 dlg_spec.menu_select("Help->About")
  File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py",
  line 723, in menu_select

menu.item_by_path(path, exact).select()
 File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py",
 line 1060, in item_by_path

lambda: len(self.top_level_parent().descendants(control_type="Menu")) > 0)
 File "D:\FromSamina\TCX3_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py",
 line 375, in wait_until

raise err **pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try `dlg_spec.wait('ready', timeout=10)` first (big timeout is more stable for slow apps), then you may need `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` which handles lazy initialization of the window on the app side (window may appear but not init the menu yet).

Comment: Okay , I will check on wait functionalities, is it possible to close an active instance of connection ?  like how we are connecting to  an active instance using app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r'D:\Asem\bin64\AUT.exe') like this I want to close the instance via code and again connect whenever I required to validate the UI element    , something like "Application(backend="uia").disconnectOrClose(path=r'D:\Asem\bin64\AUT.exe')"

Answer (score -1):

The fix for `pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out` is:

```
from pywinauto import timings

timings.Timings.slow()
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: if you are so smart why didnt you post the solution directly ? , avoid to post useless comment instead of real code .

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers